# How to convert a month (8/8/2009) into "8 August" with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date

How to convert field from the database, say, (8/8/2009) into 8 August?

Comment: You have asked 5 questions and marked none as "answered". Go back to your questions and "tick" the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = new DateTime(2009, 8, 8)
    .ToString("d MMMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-EN"));
```

Comment: where would i add that? in the controller or the view? could you give a complete example of where it goes